# Unsetting and recreating $_GET, in order to test filter_input_array()

Tags: php, arrays, validation, get

I am adding some code to legacy PHP, to use `filter_input_array()` to validate the `$_GET` parameters from the URL of an AJAX request.

Having coded the function, I naturally wanted to test it.

I am at work, posting about some code I wrote at home, so have been forced to reproduce the salient points from memeory. This code, however, does reflect the problem which I was having at home (in a clearer way thean my home code does).

My 'test' is quick & dirty. A single PHP page repeatedly cleaers `$_GET` (by unsetting it and redeclaring it), adds some parameters to it and invokes `filter_input_array()`.

I am beginning to wonder if that is valid ...

```
<?php
    echo('$_GET, at start of script<br>');
    var_dump($_GET);
    echo('<hr>');

    echo('unset($_GET), then dump it ()obviously, we expect an error<br>');
    unset($_GET);
    var_dump($_GET);
    echo('<hr>');

    echo('Now, define $_GEt as an array, and add a few items, and validate it<br>');
    $_GET = array();
    $_GET['one'] = 1;
    $_GET['two plus two'] = 5;
    var_dump($_GET);
    echo('<hr>');

    echo('Now, attempt to validate the $_GET<br>');

    $fileters = array('one' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                      'two plus two' => FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
                        );

    $validateGet = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, $fileters, false);
    echo('Validation result = ');
    var_dump($validateGet);
?>
```

gives

> $_GET, at start of script array(0) { }
>
> unset($_GET), then dump it ()obviously, we expect an error E_NOTICE :
>   type 8 -- Undefined variable: _GET -- at line 8 NULL
>
> Now, define $_GEt as an array, and add a few items, and validate it
>   array(2) { ["one"]=> int(1) ["two plus two"]=> int(5) }
>
> Now, attempt
>   to validate the $_GET
>   Validation    result = NULL

1) what is going wrong with `filter_input_array()`?

2) why is the result `null`, when the documentation says that it will be `false` on failure? Which should I be checking for? I currently use `if $validateGet === false`

Comment: it really is a bad practice to use superglobals (`$_GET, $_POST, $_REQUEST`) this way. You should use them as readonly vars. see http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/76410/251694

Comment: Documentation also says `or NULL if the variable is not set` so your `$_GET` is definitely not what `filter_input_array` expects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function filter_input_array does not seems to use `$_GET` so the changes done on this var are not used by the validation function.

If you really need to change the value of this var (which i think is not a good practice) you must replace `filter_input_array()` with `filter_var_array()`. This function uses the modified var and gives the expected result

http://ideone.com/x5D3Pb

Comment: An excellent answer. Obviously, I ought not to be chaging `$_GET` - this was only for testing and would never be in production code.